# Array display issue

Tags: zend-framework

I have a database table ("buildings") in MySQL consisting of 3 columns:

- Name
- Place
- Number

I have created a dropdown list in my view page which contains the names of the buildings and also a textarea.

Now, depending on which name the user selects, the textarea should be populated with the respective place and number of the name of the building. I’m able to get the result but I want the output to be more readable. Right now, the format of the output is as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Number] => 14
            [Place] => Cambodia
        )
)
```

Is there anyway I could get the output to be as simple as:

```
Number : 14
Place: Cambodia
```

Her's the model code:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_Building extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function getname($name)
    {
        $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $select = "SELECT * FROM buildings where name = $name";
        $stmt = $db->query($select);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        print_r ($result);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a matter of writing PHP code to access the array elements and outputting them in the manner you require. Are you familiar with the code required to access array elements, and with 'echo' or 'print' statements?

Comment: Here's my model code:

Comment: I could include the controller and ajax part as well if you want me to

Comment: The code that you posted reveals that your data is contained in an array named `$result`. At the risk of being repetitive, are you familiar with the ways of accessing array elements as defined in the PHP documentation?

Comment: Not really. I'm new to this.

Comment: That's not a problem: We were all, once. However, Stack Overflow isn't the best place to find that type of information. May I suggest that you start with the [PHP documentation on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) or with one of the many tutorials about access arrays in PHP? This will give you a solid foundation of knowledge on which to build your code, instead of one-off solutions which may not help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

instead of echoing the array dump, try:

```
foreach ($result as $vals) {
echo "Place: ".$vals["Place"]."<br>Number: ".$vals["Number"];
 }
```

as other posters have commented, you should read about php arrays so you know why this makes sense